# CSS Background Image doesn't load

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to load an image to my page and set it as my background, below is the css and html that I am working with. The CSS page seems to load, as my test font and background colors show up but for whatever reason my background image doesn't.

I am using Django as my web framework.

Appreciate the help!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/frontpagebackground.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
</head>

<body>


<p>This is a test</p>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-image:url(personal/static/personal/img/home.jpg) no-repeat;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
background-color: green;
min-height: 100%;
}


p {
    font-style: italic;
    color: red;

}
```

Comment: Remove the `no-repeat` from background-image as you already have it in a separate property `background-repeat`, and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You used `background-image`, so the `no-repeat` is not actually working. Try adding the `no-repeat` below as `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

```
 background-image: url('image-url-here.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: That, or `background: url('image-url-here.png') no-repeat;`. But he has to choose either combined properties with `background` shorthand or split properties with full names. Cannot mix.

Comment: As you like, both ways make sense as long as one remains consistent within their project.

Comment: @Phum, can you post your folder structure?

Comment: @Phum, depending on where your background image is located, you may need to change the url path reference to match it. Your current image path suggesta that the `personal` directory is on the same level as your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems like this with django, primarily because my {% static %} location was confusing me. I think this is a non-css issue, and a path issue.

It helped me to use the dev console to check for Resource Failed To Load error. It will spit out the path that the machine is looking for, and it's likely different than what you specified.

I.e. is your css file located along

```
personal/static/personal/img/home.jpg
```

relative to your css file? You might just need to back up a directory, i.e.

```
../personal/static/personal/img/home.jpg
```

Either way, the console should give you your path, and use that to determine where your CSS file is digging for the image.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSS files are in a path such as `/static/css/style.css`
and the images are under a path such as `/static/images/test.jpg`
then you have to place the `test.jpg` image directly in the folder with the `style.css` i.e. `/static/css/test.jpg` and in your HTML file give it the name `test.jpg` without using the static path i.e. `background-image:url('test.jpg');:)`